# Parse and save file/or parse string from ISO-8859-3 to UTF-8 in JSP/Java

Tags: java, jsp, parsing, utf-8, iso-8859-1

Well, it's been a while since I'm braking my head with this. I can't find a solution yet. I have tried with a lot of things, but nothing seems to work, so I would like to ask how to do this. And sorry for the bad english.

I'm doing a file upload on a JSP Web Application. Im usgin some jQuery File Upload plugin, but, I don't think that is the core of the problem (I'm not discarding, but... the file is uploaded to a temp folder, and it's ok). Anyway, the file looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iw37e.png), and as you can see, the charset is ISO-8859-3.

I retrieve data in this way:

```
request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

    if (ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request)) {
        ServletFileUpload servletFileUpload = new ServletFileUpload(new DiskFileItemFactory());
        List fileItemsList = servletFileUpload.parseRequest(request);
        Iterator it = fileItemsList.iterator();

        if (fileItemsList.size() > 0) {
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                FileItem fileItem = (FileItem) it.next();
                if (!fileItem.isFormField()) {
                    String nomCompleto = fileItem.getName();

                    saveFile = nomCompleto.substring(nomCompleto.lastIndexOf(separador) + 1).trim();

                    String ext = saveFile.substring(saveFile .lastIndexOf("."), saveFile.length());

                    if (ext.equalsIgnoreCase(".csv") || ext.equalsIgnoreCase(".txt")) {
                        fguarda = new File(ruta + saveFile);
                        fguarda.delete();
                        fileItem.write(fguarda);

                        ArrayList<String> lineas = FuncionesGenericas.leerArchivoUTF8(fguarda.getAbsolutePath());
```

May that could be the problem. The request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8") was something desperate, and I really don't know if I should delete it. But, as I said, it doesn't matter, the file is uploaded on its original charset.

I'm doing a test on a new project, with a similar method just like the one that retrieve the lines and puts them into an array (FuncionesGenericas.leerArchivoUTF-8), and where I'm trying to parse each line from ISO-8859-3 to UTF-8, but nothing seems to work. I'm always getting "?" instead of "á".

```
try {
        ArrayList<String> lineas = new ArrayList();

        FileReader fr;

        fr = new FileReader("C:\\Personal\\temp\\ffffff.txt");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(fr);
        String s;
        while ((s = in.readLine()) != null) {
            String UTF8Str = new String(s.getBytes("ISO-8859-3"), "UTF-8");
            String intento2 = new String(s.getBytes(Charset.forName("ISO-8859-3")), Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
            System.out.println("UTF8Str = " + UTF8Str);
            System.out.println("intento2 = " + intento2);


            lineas.add(UTF8Str);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("e = " + e);
    }
```

So, I'm basically trying to parse the strings from the file and store them in the array, but with a different charset, I hope someone can help me a little. I don't know if you can recommend me other way to do this. I tried a lot of things and nothing worked. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nowhere in the code Servlet code are you specifying charset `ISO-8859-3`. In fact, you call `leerArchivoUTF8`, which seems to specifically say that it is reading the file as UTF-8.

How is the server supposed to know that the file is in `ISO-8859-3`?

Your Notepad++ knows, because that is the default charset of your OS, but the server doesn't know that.

You have 2 options:

1. Use Notepad++ and save the file in UTF-8.
2. Add input field to form for specifying the charset, so the server can read the file using that charset.

---

As for your other code, you need to give the charset when you read the file.

For Java 8+:

```
List<String> lineas = Files.lines(Paths.get("C:\\Personal\\temp\\ffffff.txt"),
                                  Charset.forName("ISO-8859-3"))
                           .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

For Java 7+:

```
List<String> lineas = new ArrayList<>();
try (BufferedReader in = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get("C:\\Personal\\temp\\ffffff.txt"),
                                                 Charset.forName("ISO-8859-3"))) {
    for (String s; (s = in.readLine()) != null; ) {
        lineas.add(s);
    }
}
```

For Java 5+:

```
List<String> lineas = new ArrayList<String>();
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(
                                "C:\\Personal\\temp\\ffffff.txt"), "ISO-8859-3"));
try {
    for (String s; (s = in.readLine()) != null; ) {
        lineas.add(s);
    }
} finally {
    in.close();
}
```

Comment: Hey! What's up, Andreas? 

Sorry for the late answer, but you helped me a lot with those comments and fragments of code. I've even ended using one of them. As I said in the frist message, I tried to (and in the worst possible way) parse the file by reading and saving it in UTF-8. But, well, it didn't work.

So, then, I started to search for how to know the encoding of the file, because any of those codes you gave me returns a clean string. Then, I discovered and suffered a little with Apache Tika to know the best possible way to get the encoding and reading the file to get those strings.

Comment: Thank you for opening my mind to find a new solution! I'll post everything right below.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by other ways.

Using Apache Tika I was able to read the file encoding in the best possible way (because, in mi research I found that it's impossible to know correctly which encoding the file has), so, by getting the clean strings (strings with áéíóú, for example, not replacing it with a ?), I were able to "correctly" read the files, and get the correct strings.

The first function reads the file. The second one detects the encoding, using Apache Tika libraries (tika-app-1.17.jar).

```
public static ArrayList<String> leerArchivoUTF8(String xRuta) throws Exception {
    ArrayList<String> lineas = new ArrayList();
    String codificacion = detectarCodificacion(xRuta);
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(
                                   xRuta), codificacion));
    try {
        for (String s; (s = in.readLine()) != null; ) {
            lineas.add(s);
        }
    } finally {
        in.close();
    }
    return lineas;
}   

public static String detectarCodificacion(String xRuta) throws Exception {
    String codificacion = "";
    try {
        BufferedInputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(xRuta));
        CharsetDetector obj = new CharsetDetector();
        obj.setText(is);
        codificacion = obj.detect().getName();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        throw new Exception("Error al leer codificación: " + e);
    }
    return codificacion;
}
```